# Where to find the Prism.UnityExtensions

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

I'm unable to find the UnityExtensions for Unity for Prism 6. I'm trying to implement a composite application using Prism and Unity. The Prism 5 documentation uses this code to resolve its Shell (taken from the Commanding example):

```
public class CommandingBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    ...
}
```

I think the Resolve method is in the Prism.UnityExtensions dll for Prism 5. But the extensions are now marked as deprecated and I cannot find the extensions for Prism 6, only the Unity for Prism 6 dll on NuGet.

Is there a replacement for UnityExtensions for Prism 6 or is the Shell resolved differently under Prism 6 when Unity is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're completely right about UnityExtensions being deprecated as this was used in Prism 5. With Prism 6, everything related to using Unity is available in the [Prism.Unity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Unity/) package. The abstract UnityBootstrapper is still your base class to use.

Have a look at the [samples for Prism 6](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf) (note that the team is still in the process of porting over existing samples and adding new ones). [This file](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/HelloWorld/HelloWorld/Bootstrapper.cs#L12-L15) shows the use of the bootstrapper.

If you're missing anything in particular in the codebase, don't hesitate to log an issue.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That is really helpful to me. I really had the problem that now with Prism 4, 5 and 6 it is sometimes a bit hard to find the correct answers and Prsim 6 seems to be quite new. But it's really great that there is community support now.